# I am getting the date instead of date and time data in a POST request

Tags: javascript, django, daterangepicker

I have a [date range picker](https://www.daterangepicker.com/) on my website.

When a user inputs the date and time range, I want to send separately within the form the `startDate` and the `endDate`

daterangepicker code:

```
    $('input[name="datetimes"]').daterangepicker({
        timePicker: true,
        timePickerIncrement: 5,
        startDate: moment().startOf('hour'),
        endDate: moment().startOf('hour').add(32, 'hour'),
        locale: {
          format: 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm'
        },
        opens: 'center',
        drops: 'auto'
    });
```

And this is what I tried:

```
$('#formid').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let startDate = ($('#datetimes').data('daterangepicker').startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm');
    let endDate = ($('#datetimes').data('daterangepicker').endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm');
    $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="start_date" value='+startDate+' /> ');
    $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="end_date" value='+endDate+' /> ');
    this.submit();
});
```

Before the `this.submit();` I did a `console.log(startDate)` and thi is what I am getting:

[image]

I am getting the date and the time (as expected), but then if I try doing a `print(request.POST)` in the view (django back-end), this is what I get:

[image]

Somehow, during the `POST` the `HH:mm` disappeared.

How can I keep the values of `hh:mm` during the POST?

Update:

`views.py`

```
def add_new_task(request):
    context = {}
    context['nbar'] = 'index'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST)
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

`models.py`

```
class ToDoList(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    description = models.TextField()
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    )
```

Comment: start_date is a DateTimeField() right? Share your views and models too.

Comment: Exactly. Views and models added. Thank you!

Comment: make sure the js part is sending the full date by inspecting the POST request data from the Network tab in the developer tools of your browser

Comment: I can't see anything weird. If I hardcode the date, e.g `2021-11-30 11:00` I can receive it in the back-end but if I use the startDate and endDate data the hours and minutes are missing.

Comment: seem like the issue of moment?

Comment: What makes you think is an issue of moment?

Comment: maybe moment.startOf is trimming the date, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a long shot, but is it possible that the fact that you're missing double quotes around the `value` attributes in your hidden inputs, is what's causing the issue?

Try changing it to:

```
$(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="start_date" value="'+startDate+'" /> ');
$(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="end_date" value="'+endDate+'" /> ');
```

Comment: Genius, that was it